# Digital Soil Map of the World

Tags: qgis, shapefile, mapping, soil

I have downloaded a digital soil map of the world from: https://worldmap.harvard.edu/data/geonode:DSMW_RdY

It has lots of files in it with different endings (shp, sbx, xls etc.). I am using QGIS 3.4. When I add vector layer and add the shapefile, all it does is loads a bunch of polygons with no soil colour to differentiate them (they are all the same colour). When I try to load all the files in the zip file at once, the same thing happens.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Hi Donald. The questions you are asking are extremely basic. Please check out the QGIS user manual: https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/training_manual/ Particularly page: https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/training_manual/vector_classification/classification.html

Comment: Unless a preset style (qml-file) with the same name as the shape file is provided, QGis always loads new data with a single colour. How should a program know, which data-column you want to differentiate by?

Comment: I think I have got it now. Thanks for the help everyone!